Handle a chain of then() blocks for a redirect in node.js using Moongose
I have the following code but I'm getting an error message stating that I'm trying to modify the headers after sending the redirect. I think it is the way I handle the if statement and the returns. I've modified the code and now the redirect works, but I think I'm misunderstanding the logic. See the first code here:
exports.postSignup = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
  // check if user exist
  User.findOne({ emailAddress: email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("user exists please log in!");
        return res.redirect("/auth/login");
      }
      const newUser = new User({
        emailAddress: email,
        password: password,
        cart: {
          products: [],
        },
      });
      return newUser.save();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("added user");
        res.redirect("/auth/login");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      throw e;
    });
};

fixed version that works:
exports.postSignup = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
  // check if user exist
  User.findOne({ emailAddress: email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("user exists please log in!");
        return res.redirect("/auth/login");
      }
      const newUser = new User({
        emailAddress: email,
        password: password,
        cart: {
          products: [],
        },
      });
      return newUser.save();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // this makes the redirect only if the user is created
      if (result) {
        console.log("added user");
        res.redirect("/auth/login");
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      throw e;
    });
};

Can someone help me figuring out why the earlier version doesn't work? I can only imagine that I'm call the redirect() twice.

The first .then() does return res.redirect(). This does not stop the promise chain - the second .then() is still executed. You may want to take a look at Using promises

As per the docs:

Mongoose queries are not promises. Queries are thenables, meaning they have a .then() method for async/await as a convenience

I recommend adopting async/await pattern which you can read about in the docs but please note:

that the specific fulfillment values of different Mongoose methods vary, and may be affected by configuration. Please refer to the API documentation for information about specific methods.

In this part of your code:
if (user) {
   console.log("user exists please log in!");
   return res.redirect("/auth/login");
}

You are returning a res.redirect to the next then() chain. You are then calling res.redirect again.
However in this part of your code:
return newUser.save();

You are returning the result from the settled promise because the save() method is asynchronous.
Using async/await would like this:
exports.postSignup = async (req, res) => { //< mark function as async
    try{
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
        const user = await User.findOne({ emailAddress: email }); //< use await keyword
        if(user){
            console.log("user exists please log in!");
            return res.redirect("/auth/login"); //< early return
        }else{
            const newUser = new User({
                emailAddress: email,
                password: password,
                cart: {
                    products: [],
                },
            });
            await newUser.save(); //< use await keyword
            console.log("added user");
            res.redirect("/auth/login");
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        // handle err
    }
};

